# Heat kernel and laplacian

Tags: image-processing

Is there any relation between heat kernel and Laplacian? I know what each of them is but I am not sure about the relation between them.

Comment: The Wikipedia article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel makes the distinction with its first two equations and clearly shows their relationship (although I admit its notation is abominable).

Comment: @whuber: Thank you but it didn't say more than a few words.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't clear about that last remark. By following the link to the [definition of the Laplace operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Definition) we see that in the [heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) $$\frac{\partial K}{\partial t}(t,x,y)=\Delta_x K(t,x,y)$$ the Laplacian "$\Delta_x$" must be with respect to the vector variable $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_d)$ and is given by $$\Delta_x=\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}.$$